# Implementing a queue using a circular buffer

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.x, queue, circular-list

I'm working on implementing a queue using a circular buffer problem. Any smarter ideas for better time complexity, any code bug or code style advice are highly appreciated.

```
class QueueOnCirciularBuffer:
    def __init__(self, max_size):
        self.buffer = [0]*max_size
        self.index = 0 # element to write
        self.size = 0
        self.max_size = max_size
    def push_element(self, value):
        if self.size == self.max_size:
            raise Exception('queue full')
        self.buffer[self.index] = value
        self.index += 1
        self.size += 1
        self.index = self.index % self.max_size
    def pop_element(self):
        if self.size > 0:
            value = self.buffer[(self.index - self.size+self.max_size)%self.max_size]
            self.size -= 1
            return value
        else:
            raise Exception('empty queue')
    def peak_element(self):
        if self.size > 0:
            return self.buffer[(self.index-1+self.max_size)%self.max_size]
        else:
            raise Exception('empty queue')
if __name__ == "__main__":
    q = QueueOnCirciularBuffer(16)
    q.push_element(1)
    q.push_element(2)
    print q.peak_element() # output 2
    q.pop_element()
    print q.peak_element() # output 2

    q2 = QueueOnCirciularBuffer(3)
    for i in range(3):
        print i
        q2.push_element(i)
    for i in range(10):
        print q2.pop_element()
        q2.push_element(i)
```

Comment: It is spelled "peek" (look quickly or furtively), not "peak" (the pointed top of a mountain).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Advice 1**

**`QueueOnCirciularBuffer`**: you misspelled **`Circular`**

**Advice 2**

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) gives more canonic names for the data structure. Why not choose, say, **`CircularBuffer`**?

**Advice 3**

Instead of having a single index **`self.index`**, why not take two: **`self.head_index`** is the index in the underlying storage array holding the head element of the buffer; **`self.tail_index`** points into the array location at which next element is inserted. If not efficiency, this adds to maintainability in my opinion.

**Advice 4**

```
value = self.buffer[(self.index - self.size+self.max_size)%self.max_size]
self.buffer[(self.index-1+self.max_size)%self.max_size]
```

Adding **`self.max_size`** has not effect since you take the modulo of it.

**Advice 5**

[PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) complains about some aspects of your code layout. Consider using a Python IDE (I use PyCharm); it gives you instant feedback if your code does not adhere to rules in PEP 8.

**Advice 6**

Its funny that your **`peak_element`** returns the tail element of the queue; why not rename it to, say, **`peak_tail`**. (And possibly provide **`peak_head`**.)

**Summa summarum**

All in all, I had this in mind:

```
class CircularBuffer:
    def __init__(self, capacity):
        self.buffer = [0] * capacity
        self.size = 0
        self.capacity = capacity
        self.head_index = 0
        self.tail_index = 0

    def push_element(self, value):
        if self.size == self.capacity:
            raise Exception('The circular buffer is full.')
        self.buffer[self.tail_index] = value
        self.tail_index = (self.tail_index + 1) % self.capacity
        self.size += 1

    def pop_element(self):
        if self.size == 0:
            raise Exception('Popping from an empty circular buffer.')
        ret = self.buffer[self.head_index]
        self.head_index = (self.head_index + 1) % self.capacity
        self.size -= 1
        return ret

    def peek_head(self):
        if self.size == 0:
            raise Exception('Peeking into an empty circular buffer.')
        return self.buffer[self.head_index]
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks coderodde. Love all of your comments and mark your reply as answer. I am using Pycharm, but on Windows. Do you know how to set it up for PEB-8 style checking?

Comment: @LinMa I work on Mac, so hard to tell. For me it works by wave-underlining the expression that does not conform to PEP 8. Taking the mouse to that line gives me the feedback in form of a pop-up.

Comment: Do you install some additional plug-ins for PEB-8?

Comment: @LinMa No, no plug-ins whatsoever. Once again, if you have an expression that does not conform to PEP 8 (try, for example, **`i+=1`**), PyCharm will underline that expression with a wavy line. Move the cursor to that wavy line and PyCharm will tell you what's wrong.

Comment: Thanks, I will do some study how to enable it on Windows. Are you using free edition of Pycharm or paid? Not sure if free version has this feature?

Comment: @LinMa I use the Community edition, which is free. Note, however, that I did not have to "enable" it or something; it worked out of the box.

Comment: @LinMa Try this link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1anucvl8b73cd31/PyCharm.png?dl=0  If it ask you to sign in, press something like "Continue without signing in."

Comment: Thanks man, I already found it. It is not red color so not attract too much my attention. :)

Comment: @LinMa Good. Now just don't stop writing that funky Python code! :)